# static/Shared in VB.NET and C# visibility

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, accessor

I have faced with a situation in VB.NET and C# (.NET2) with the visibility of the static/shared members. It seems to me a little strange in VB.NET:

```
    public class A 
    {
        private static A instance;
        public static A Instance 
        {
            get { return instance; }
        }

        public string Name { get { } }
    }
```

*usage*:
`A.Instance.Name` // **ONLY Name is "visible"**

---

VB.NET:

```
Public Class A
  Private Shared _instance As A

  Public Shared ReadOnly Property Instance() As A
    Get
      Return _instance
    End Get
  End Property


  Public ReadOnly Property Name() As String
    Get
      Return ""
    End Get
  End Property

End Class
```

*usage*:

```
A.Instance.Instance.Instance.Instance...
```

**// shared member behaves like a class public one I can repeat it to infinite..**

is this a Microsoft oversight or a VB.NET "feature"?

Comment: if this is true then I'll add it to my list of 'why C# rather than VB' ;-)

Comment: @AdamRalph: and this would be premature and unreflected.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's not an oversight but your VB code **will** trigger a warning, which plainly means: do not use this notation.

In VB, static members *can* be accessed via an instance, since strictly speaking, VB **doesn’t have `static`**: VB has the keyword `Shared`, meaning that the member is *shared* between all instances, as opposed to `static` where a member doesn’t belong to *any* instance.

Now, this is a semantical distinction between those keywords. It just so happens that these two distinct semantics tend to have the exact same effect.

Of course, `static` in C# is today identical to `Shared` in VB.NET but their legacy is different and VB’s `Shared` simply has a different history and therefore historically a different meaning. With *this* meaning, it makes absolutely sense to access `Shared` members via an instance.

It also makes sense when used together with `Option Strict Off` (loose typing): here, you sometimes *don’t know* a variable’s type but you still might want to access a `Shared` member. Now, you’ve got no choice but to use an instance to access it:

```
Option Strict Off
' … '
Dim o As Object = New A()
' Somewhere else, we want to access a static member of A but we don’t know A: '
Dim instance = o.Instance
```

Comment: C# seems to be more accurate and clear that VB.NET that should take in consideration its "historical" compatibility with VB family. 
Anyway, C# does not allow duplicates in the visibility of static members - via the class name and via class instance. Also it prevents the "infinitize" the field calls like Instance.StaticMember.StaticMember... this could embarrass the user of the class instance.

Answer (score 11):

It is a feature; this is not a bug. VB is working as designed. Different languages make different choices about whether a static method can be treated as a method of an instance or not. VB allows it. C++ allows it. C# does not.

Remember, the design criteria of different languages are different, and therefore the decisions made are different. On the C# design team, we highly value a language definition which makes illegal patterns that look suspicious; since there's no *meaning* to passing an instance as the receiver to a static method (unless computing the receiver expression causes a side effect) then why allow the user to type meaningless code?

On the VB design team, they value the code working *the way you meant it to work* the the first time you typed it; if something looks a bit dodgy, maybe give a warning, but allow it and move on.

If you're interested in some of the more subtle issues in the design of static calls in C#, here's an interesting issue:

http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/07/06/color-color.aspx

Comment: really, as I considered my Instance more *static* than *shared* I didn't expect to have one more *Instance* in the singleton *Instance* and so one...

Answer (score 0):

The C# compiler won't allow you to reference a static property on an instance of an object, only on the type itself. This is a C# rather than a .NET CLR restriction. VB.NET will allow this but will warn against it.

Comment: *This is a C# rather than a .NET CLR restriction.*
This restriction is a good one, IMHO, because don't duplicate the visibility of static members - via the class name and via class instance. Also this prevent to "infinitize" the field calls like Instance.StaticMember.StaticMember.StaticMember.StaticMember.StaticMember...