# How to call a C# class's static method from VB.Net?

Tags: c#, vb.net, dll, reference

I have a C# dll and want to use it in VB.NET. I'm using C# 2008 Express and VB 2008 Express. I have added a reference in a VB project to the C# dll. When I create an instane of a class in the C# dll, it gives the following error messsage: "Type 'RF.RabinFingerprint' has no constructors". How do I fix this?

My C# dll code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace RF
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Génère des empreintes de fichiers
    /// </summary>
    public static class RabinFingerprint
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Bit 64 of the polynomial P is always 1 and not treated directly. This is the polynomial
        /// with the leading coefficient removed (lcr).
        /// Represents t^64 + t^4 + t^3 + t + 1.
        /// </summary>
        private static readonly UInt64 p_lcr = 0x000000000000001BL;
        /// <summary>
        /// It's not necessary to provide definitions for such integral constant variables as long as their
        /// addresses are not taken.
        /// Degree of the polynomial P.
        /// </summary>
        private static readonly int K = 64;
        /// <summary>
        /// Represents t^(K-1)
        /// </summary>
        private static readonly UInt64 T_K_minus_1 = (UInt64)1L << (K - 1);
        /// <summary>
        /// Broder's paper presents four pre-computed tables because words are considered to be 32-bit.
        /// In this implementation W is a 64-bit integral type. Eight tables are used.
        /// Table A is i1^127 + i2^126 + ... + i8^120.
        /// Table B is i1^119 + i2^118 + ... + i8^112.
        /// Table C, D, ..
        /// Table E is i1^95  + i2^94  + ... + i8^88. (This is table A in the paper.)
        /// Table F, G, H.
        /// </summary>
        private static UInt64[] tableA_ = new UInt64[256]; //Assuming byte size 8.
        private static UInt64[] tableB_ = new UInt64[256];
        private static UInt64[] tableC_ = new UInt64[256];
        private static UInt64[] tableD_ = new UInt64[256];
        private static UInt64[] tableE_ = new UInt64[256];
        private static UInt64[] tableF_ = new UInt64[256];
        private static UInt64[] tableG_ = new UInt64[256];
        private static UInt64[] tableH_ = new UInt64[256];
        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor
        /// </summary>
        static RabinFingerprint()
        {
            InitTables();
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Initialize tables
        /// </summary>
        private static void InitTables()
        {
            //This represents t^(k + i) mod P, where i is the index of the array.
            //It will be used to compute the tables.
            UInt64[] mods = new UInt64[K];
            //Remember t^k mod P is equivalent to p_lcr.
            mods[0] = p_lcr;
            for (int i = 1; i < K; ++i)
            {
                //By property: t^i mod P = t(t^(i - 1)) mod P.
                mods[i] = mods[i - 1] << 1;
                //If mods[i - 1] had a term at k-1, mods[i] would have had the term k, which is not represented.
                //The term k would account for exactly one more division by P. Then, the effect is the same
                //as adding p_lcr to the mod.
                if ((mods[i - 1] & T_K_minus_1) != 0)
                    mods[i] ^= p_lcr;
            }
            //Compute tables. A control variable is used to indicate whether the current bit should be
            //considered.
            for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
            {
                int control = i;
                for (int j = 0; j < 8 && control > 0; ++j)
                {
                    // bool.Parse(Convert.ToString())
                    if ((control & 1) == 1) //Ok, consider bit. ((byte))
                    {
                        tableA_[i] ^= mods[j + 56];
                        tableB_[i] ^= mods[j + 48];
                        tableC_[i] ^= mods[j + 40];
                        tableD_[i] ^= mods[j + 32];
                        tableE_[i] ^= mods[j + 24];
                        tableF_[i] ^= mods[j + 16];
                        tableG_[i] ^= mods[j + 8];
                        tableH_[i] ^= mods[j];
                    }
                    control >>= 1;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Compute hash key
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">Value to hash</param>
        /// <returns>Value</returns>
        private static UInt64 ComputeTablesSum(ref UInt64 value)
        {
            value = tableH_[((value) & 0xFF)] ^
                    tableG_[((value >> 8) & 0xFF)] ^
                    tableF_[((value >> 16) & 0xFF)] ^
                    tableE_[((value >> 24) & 0xFF)] ^
                    tableD_[((value >> 32) & 0xFF)] ^
                    tableC_[((value >> 40) & 0xFF)] ^
                    tableB_[((value >> 48) & 0xFF)] ^
                    tableA_[((value >> 56) & 0xFF)];
            return value; //Pass by reference to return the same w. (Convenience and efficiency.)
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Compute hask hey
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="HashArray">Array of Ulong bytes to ahsh</param>
        /// <returns>Hash key</returns>
        private static UInt64 Compute(UInt64[] HashArray)
        {
            UInt64 w = 0L;
            for (int s = 0; s < HashArray.Length; ++s)
                w = ComputeTablesSum(ref w) ^ HashArray[s];
            return w;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Compute the fingerprint
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="source">String to compute</param>
        /// <returns>Hash key</returns>
        public static UInt64 ComputeFingerPrint(string source)
        {
            byte[] table = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(source);
            UInt64[] values = new UInt64[table.LongLength];
            ConvertBytes(ref table, ref values);
            return Compute(values);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Compute the fingerprint, you must use this method for very large text
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="source">String to compute</param>
        /// <returns>Hash key</returns>
        public static UInt64 ComputeFingerPrint(ref string source)
        {
            return ComputeFingerPrint(source);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Compute the fingerprint, you must use this method for very large binary data
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="source">Data to compute</param>
        /// <returns>Hash key</returns>
        public static UInt64 ComputeFingerPrint(ref byte[] source)
        {
            UInt64[] values = new UInt64[source.LongLength];
            ConvertBytes(ref source, ref values);
            return Compute(values);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Compute the fingerprint, you must use this method for very large binary data
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="source">Data to compute</param>
        /// <returns>Hash key</returns>
        public static UInt64 ComputeFingerPrint(byte[] source)
        {
            return ComputeFingerPrint(ref source);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Compute byte array to Uint64 array
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="source">Table de byte source</param>
        /// <param name="destination">Tableau de Uin64</param>
        private static void ConvertBytes(ref byte[] source, ref UInt64[] destination)
        {
            for (long i = 0; i < source.LongLength; i++)
                destination[i] = Convert.ToUInt64(source[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

My VB code:

```
Imports RF

Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim t As New RabinFingerprint

    End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to use instances, you need to add a non-static constructor to the C# class - currently it's only got a static constructor.

There is info on diffs between static/shared in VB.Net and C# [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980207/static-shared-in-vb-net-and-c-visibility) that could be useful in resolving this.

If you were doing this in C# you just call the class's static methods like

```
UInt64 result = RabinFingerprint.ComputeFIngerprint(...);
```

etc.

In VB.Net this looks something like this:

```vb
Dim result = RF.RabinFingerprint.ComputeFingerprint(...)
```

Here is an [example from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy.aspx) of what I mean.  Here both `Console.WriteLine` and `Regex.Split` are static, just like your class's methods.

```vb
Dim input As String = "plum--pear"
Dim pattern As String = "-"          ' Split on hyphens

Dim substrings() As String = Regex.Split(input, pattern)
For Each match As String In substrings
   Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", match)
Next
' The method writes the following to the console:
'    'plum'
'    ''
'    'pear'
```

Comment: It is `Dim result = RF.RabinFingerprint.ComputeFingerprint(...)`

Comment: @Hans - thanks.  Will this work otherwise?  It seems like it should.

Comment: Yup, after you remove the semi-colon.

Comment: Whatever I try, I cannot see or use the members of the C#-class in VB.

Comment: @iar - can you edit your question to include revised C# and VB.Net code, and what error you are getting?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have no constructors because your class is declared as static

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use it from C#?

It probably gives you the same error there.

**EDIT**

I have tried your code. (Jeff we **need** a **copy source code button**)

IN VB.NET. There's the following error:

```
Type 'RF.RabinFingerprint' has no constructors.
```

In C# you get the following 2 errors.

```
Cannot create an instance of the static class 'RF.RabinFingerprint'
Cannot declare a variable of static type 'RF.RabinFingerprint'
```

Actually C# shows you the real problem. As Jazz have mentioned. You should change your class to be nonstatic to work properly

**EDIT2**

Steve is right. If your class has been designed to be static as it appears since everything in there is static, then what has to be changed is the call to the constructor. Since the class is static you can't create an instance of your class.

**There is no need to call the constructor because it will be automatically called the first time the class is used (For example when you call a method from it).**

Comment: Doesn't VB.Net support access of static methods on .Net framework classes though?  Why convert if static throughout is preferable?