# What are the differences between Shared and Static?

Tags: c#, vb.net, static, static-methods, shared

I'm a C# developer but I've inherited a legacy VB app today with 0 documentation what so ever. I've been starting to read through the code and reference the [list of VB keywords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ksh7h19t(v=vs.90).aspx) every 5 seconds.

I guess I don't understand the distinction between `Shared` and `Static`.

Reading this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1980293/1189566

It states:

> VB doesn't have `static`, it has `shared`

But you can see in the list of keywords linked above, `Static` is a reserved keyword. It looks like `Static` is only applicable to fields, where as `Shared` can be on a method **or** a field?

I guess ultimately I'm just hoping someone could expand upon the answer I linked to provide some more details for a VB noob.

For example, say I had this

```
public class MyClass
    Dim myVar as Integer = 1

    public shared sub UpdateMyVar()
        myVar = 2
    end sub
end class

public class MyOtherClass
    Dim cOne = New MyClass()
    Dim cTwo = New MyClass()

    cOne.UpdateMyVar()
    txtMyTextBox.Text = cTwo.myVar.ToString()
end class
```

Please forgive any syntactical issues. Assume this code compiles. I've literally just started skimming the code an hour and a half ago.

Would `cTwo.myVar` be `1` or `2`? I'm guessing `2` since `Shared` seems to affect all instances of a class? That seems tremendously dangerous.

Comment: "Static" in VB applies only to local variables - it means that the variable will hold it's value between method calls. E.g., Static i As Integer = 2.  It's not used often, but there it is.

Comment: You cannot assign a non-shared variable from a shared method.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The equivalent of the C# `Static` *method* modifier is `Shared` in VB.net

The closest equivalent of the C# `Static` *class* modifier in VB.Net is a `Module`

The `Static` keyword in VB.NET defines a local variable that exists for the lifetime of the process. There is no equivalent of this in C#.

For a great reference of comparison between the two see this link: https://www.harding.edu/fmccown/vbnet_csharp_comparison.html

Comment: Awesome link, I've been messing around with a VB-C# conversion tool online to try and understand things better but it was very poor. This seems much nicer.

Answer (score 3):

For VB.Net you use shared exactly like Static is used in C#, but VB.Net has a static keyword as well and it is used to retain a variable value even after the method call has ended.  So the next time you call a method it will have that previous value.  MSDN has a more detailed explanation here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2cty7t8.aspx

From the link there are some interesting behaviors:

> When you declare a static variable in a Shared procedure, only one
>   copy of the static variable is available for the whole application.
>   You call a Shared procedure by using the class name, not a variable
>   that points to an instance of the class.
>
> When you declare a static
>   variable in a procedure that isn't Shared, only one copy of the
>   variable is available for each instance of the class. You call a
>   non-shared procedure by using a variable that points to a specific
>   instance of the class.