# Is there a true VB.NET equivalent to C#'s static class?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I like c#'s static classes because they can't be instantiated or inherited.  They act like a namespace that can't be imported into the code file which allows for more managed organization.  It doesn't seem that VB.NET has anything truly like this.

`Modules` - They're static, but everything within them is available in the global application scope which just clutters everything.

`MustInherit` - Keeps the class from being instantiated, but can still be inherited and then instantiated.

`NotInheritable` - Can't be inherited, but can be instantiated.

I guess I can settle for `MustInherit`, but I'd really like to see the c# equivalent of a static class.

Answer (score 0):

`Shared` is basically the same as Static.

[static/Shared in VB.NET and C# visibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980207/static-shared-in-vb-net-and-c-sharp-visibility)

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. There's no static class per-say but you can use `Shared` which offers similar functionality on members. See here on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc2b427x.aspx).