# Is C#'s static the same as NotInheritable in VB.NET?

Tags: c#, vb.net

A class that contains utility methods is needed over and over all over the place. So, I'd like to make it a static class.

Why **static** is being converted to **NotInheritable**?

```
public static class MyClass 
{
    public static string MyProperty { get; set; } 

    public static void MyMethod()
    {

    }
}
```

to

```
Public NotInheritable Class Employee
   Private Sub New()
   End Sub
   Public Shared Property MyProperty() As String
      Get
          Return m_MyProperty
      End Get
      Set
          m_MyProperty = Value
      End Set
  End Property
  Private Shared m_MyProperty As String

  Public Shared Sub MyMethod()
  End Sub
 End Class
```

In my opinion, this looks more like a sealed class, doesn't it?

Comment: "NotInheritable" is the equivalent of "sealed" in c#. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h278d2d4.aspx. It seems that "Shared" is the equivalent of "static"? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980207/static-shared-in-vb-net-and-c-sharp-visibility

Comment: The static means sealed which means you can't inherit them.... Also cannot contain an instance constructor, but a static one ...

Comment: @Codexer, well it gets a bit complex. In C# you can inherit from a static class, however it's not "proper" inheritance, it's "faked". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281775/c-sharp-static-member-inheritance-why-does-this-exist-at-all

Comment: What converter did you use?  You're right, it made it a sealed class rather than static.

Comment: @Codexer, static != sealed.  See Squimmy's correct answer below.

Comment: @Joshua are you saying Microsoft is wrong? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx

Comment: @MatthewWhited thank you for confirming this.

Comment: Static classes are sealed but sealed classes are not all static.

Comment: @Codexer, no. I won't go so far as to say that you are mistaken, but instead I'll limit myself to say that your comment of "the static means sealed" is incorrect.  Those two access modifiers are not the same.  A static class is sealed, but a sealed class is not static.

The only comparable modifier to NotInheritable is Sealed.  A Static class in VB is a Module.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Why static is being converted to NotInheritable?

It's not getting *directly* converted. The fact that `static` classes are `sealed` is what makes the equivalent class in VB.NET `NonInheritable`

> In my opinion, this looks more like a sealed class, doesn't it?

Yes, but it's not "wrong" because static classes are also sealed.

VB.NET does not have the concept of a "static class". The closest it has is module, which is not the *exact* equivalent of `static` since it cannot, for example, nest another module within it, while you can define a static class within another static class in C#. So the converter may just be erring on the side of caution by not translating a `static` class to a `Module`.

Since static classes in C# are sealed classes that can't be instantiated, the closest thing to an equivalent class in VB.NET is a `NotInheritable` class with all `Shared` methods and properties, with a private default instance constructor so the class cannot be instantiated.

So the resulting VB class has all of the characteristics of the source class, but the mechanisms to provide those features are somewhat different.

Comment: You're right that the closest equivalent in VB is 'Module', but why would you say that it can't be represented in a pure code conversion?

Comment: @DaveDoknjas: That make sense. Just to be in the safe side, what about the controversy between `Shared` and `Module`? Shouldn't I for instance, write either of one to indicate my real intention? I want a static class, not a sealed class per se, even if static imply sealed?

Comment: @Richard77: I don't 'get' the controversy - 'Module' is as close as you can get to a C# static class.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas: I've read a couple of place where it was said that Module is a old way of doing things. Can you write the above code with Module keyword instead of inheritance?

Comment: @DaveDoknjas I'll have to look more but I believe there are some differences between `Module` in VB and `static class` in C# that make them not exactly equivalent.  One that comes to mind is that you cannot "nest" modules in VB but you can have a class (static or not) defined within a static class in C#.

Comment: @Richard77 I haven't seen anything official to that extent, so I'd say that's just the opinion of those that don't fully respect VB.

Comment: @DStanley: You are correct - VB modules cannot be nested, but I think this is mostly academic since I can't remember noticing anyone using nested static classes in C#.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure what you've used to convert `static` to `NotInheritable`, but they are not equivalent.

[`NotInheritable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h278d2d4.aspx) in VB.NET is equivalent to `sealed` in C#.
C#'s `static` is called [`Shared`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc2b427x.aspx) in VB.NET.

Of note, is that `Shared` cannot be applied to classes, only members of a class. This is outlined in the [VB.NET specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa712050(v=vs.71).aspx)

[Class Declarations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711939(v=vs.71).aspx):

```
ClassDeclaration ::=
   [ Attributes ] [ ClassModifier+ ] Class Identifier LineTerminator
   [ ClassBase ]
   [ TypeImplementsClause+ ]
   [ ClassMemberDeclaration+ ]
   End Class LineTerminator
ClassModifier ::= AccessModifier | Shadows | MustInherit | NotInheritable
```

(note the conspicuous lack of `Shared` under `ClassModifier ::=`)

As mentioned by other users, a `Module` is a better equivalent to a C# `static` class.

Comment: What's is confusing is that, in some articles online, it's said that `shared` is enforced by the compiler - whatever that means. Some other articles say that the equivalent of static should be `Module`. Yet, others criticize `Module` as it supposed to be a VBScript relic. I'm lost.

Comment: That telerik conversion tool looks wrong. Try to convert C# -> VB, take the result and convert back to c#

Comment: @alex.b What _should_ the output be if the converter is wrong?  The resulting C# class has the same characteristics (sealed, no instance methods, no public constructor) without using the `static` keyword.

Comment: @DStanley: The output 'should' be 'Module' - this is identical to a C# static class (with some added VB magic which allows calling members without qualification - but that's just VB magic, not the nature of 'Module' itself).

Answer (score 1):

The OP asked (in the comments) for a version using 'Module' - here it is:

```
Public Module [MyClass]
    Public Property MyProperty() As String

    Public Sub MyMethod()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Note that the members of the module are called either with qualification:

```
Dim s As String = [MyClass].MyProperty
```

Or without qualification (this is what I referred to as 'VB magic' in my comment) - I'm not recommending this - just showing for completeness:

```
Dim s As String = MyProperty
```

And yes, this is an older feature, but it is still the feature in VB that is the closest to a C# static class - there is no 'Shared Class' in VB (yet).

Comment: So there's not shared class in VB.NET. And Module's members are implicitly shared.

Comment: @Richard77: Correct (and module members can be called without using the module name, but this is a common bad practice).